# Correct way to delete a vector of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Given the next snipped:

```
vector<cv::Mat> list; // Hold the pointer values (not the pointers)

for (int index = 0; index < item_count; index++)
{
    jobject bitmap = env->GetObjectArrayElement(listBitmaps, index);

    // BitmapUtils::toMat returns a cv::Mat* which has been created with "new cv::Mat()"
    cv::Mat* mat = BitmapUtils::toMat(bitmap);

    list.push_back(*mat); // Store the object value
}
```

Is next the correct way to delete the vector object pointers?

```
for (auto entry : sources)
{
    delete & entry;
}
```

Note that I can't use a vector of pointers such as **vector<cv::Mat *>**.

Comment: What is `sources`? I can't see `new` in your code. Why do you want to `delete` something? Don't `delete` memory that isn't allocated with `new`.

Comment: @eerorika how? Is there another way to delete vector elements?

Comment: @AtahanAtay Passing address of an automatic object to `delete` is never correct.

Comment: Do you have some doc about `BitmapUtils::toMat` ? I can't find info about it, to know if it keep ownership or not

Comment: @Tomas Sabik The utility method   BitmapUtils::toMat converts bitmap objects to Mat pointers, the return value is from a cv::Mat* mat = new cv::Mat() which is populated with the bitmap pixels.

Comment: _"Note that I can't use a vector of pointers such as vector<cv::Mat *>."_ Why not? `list.push_back(*mat);` pushes  a copy of the object pointed by `mat` into the list. You are not allowed to `delete` it. Perhaps you want to `delete` `mat` after you pushed the copy into `list`.

Comment: Can you edit that line to get a shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer?

Comment: @Tomas Sabik, the method which is from openCV that expects the sources doesn't accept a vector of pointers

Comment: We don't have the definition of `cv::Mat`, but if it's an object, then the vector's destructor will delete its contents as they are removed; read up on [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).  So, `list.clear()`.  If `cv:Mat` is a pointer, you'll at least want to remove the `&` from the `delete`; but rather than that, you may want to look into `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` which will manage the pointers for you.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's in the `sources` vector. It could be a vector of anything, and the shown `delete` is actually guaranteed to be completely wrong, and result in a pretty much guaranteed crash for at least two separate, independent reasons (`entry` is in automatic scope and vector members are not individually `new`ed and even if they were it's the vector job to delete it, so there are actually three reasons).

Comment: Please provice a [mcve].

Comment: If you need to delete anything, it's `mat`. The vector will contain copies, and will manage it's own memory.

Comment: `vector<cv::Mat> list; // Hold the pointer values` This assumption is wrong. It holds copies of the pointer values. These copies have automatic storage duration. You are not allowed to `delete` them. Why do you think that something should be `delete`d?

Comment: You could just make it `vector<std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat>> list;` and get rid of the extra copy that is done in `list.push_back(*mat);`. Just make it `list.push_back(mat);` - and you then don't have to worry about `delete`ing.

Comment: @Ted the problem is that the receiver function for sources in openCV doesn't accept a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat>>. It expects std::vector<cv::Mat>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Is next the correct way to delete the vector object pointers?"* No, it's not.

If `sources` has type `vector<cv::Mat *>` you have to `delete` the pointers with

```
for (auto entry : sources)
{
    delete entry;
}
```

The vector `vector<cv::Mat> list;` has automatic storage duration. It will be automatically destroyed at the end of its block. It will allocate and deallocate the memory for its elements. You are not allowed to `delete` the vector or its elements.

If you have to `delete` the pointer returned by `cv::Mat* mat = BitmapUtils::toMat(bitmap);` you could do it this way:

```
vector<cv::Mat> list; // Hold the pointer values

for (int index = 0; index < item_count; index++)
{
    jobject bitmap = env->GetObjectArrayElement(listBitmaps, index);

    // BitmapUtils::toMat returns a cv::Mat* which has been created with "new cv::Mat()"
    cv::Mat* mat = BitmapUtils::toMat(bitmap);

    list.push_back(*mat); // Store the object value
    delete mat;
}
```

Comment: The storage duration of the elements is not "automatic". Cppreference calls it "allocated storage duration".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But it also lists four types of storage duration: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration

Comment: I have a doubt, as cv::Mat has been created in the heap, since it is created with the 'new' keyword, if I do delete as your example right after pushing to the vector, wouldn't be the Mat lost? I mean isn't it deleted from the heap and therefore no longer valid even in the vector?

Comment: @API_1024 `list.push_back(*mat);` pushes a copy. After the copy is pushed you can `delete` `mat`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I guess "allocated" is a wrong word, since I got it from a [page about C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). The page you linked calls it "dynamic".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, it's wrong because I wanted to stress that it's not allowed to `delete` the elements. I changed the paragraph.

Comment: @ThomasSabik, I've done the test with your annotations and yes it works as you mention. I deleted right after pushing to the vector, and the Mat objects are still usable. So, is it correct to assume that the Mat objects will not be leaked and they will auto-delete when going out of scope? even if the Mat instances have been created with the 'new' keyword?

Comment: @API_1024 Yes, that's correct. You created a dynamic object with `new`. You copied the object into a STL vector. You `delete`d the first object. The STL vector will `delete` its elements when it's destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

When a Vector instance is reaching its end of scope (end of life) then the destructor of all its containing objects are called. So if you have objects in a vector (not pointers to objects) then you don't need to do any explicit call of deletes, not counting the one in that your object's destructor.

In contrast, if you have pointers in a vector, you need to call delete on those pointers, if you want to release their associated objects, making sure they're still pointing to existing objects (i.e. not deleted already by some other part of code).

Finally, to make sure you don't have memory leaks, it's always a good idea and advised to make a test run of your program with Valgrind.